# uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::BootstrapPagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I have installed the will_paginate-bootstrap gem to use bootstrap style pagination. I have this in my view:

```
    <%= will_paginate @mylist, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

but it returns this error

```
    uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::BootstrapPagination
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have successfully bundle all the gems then it should work like this.

```
<%= will_paginate @mylist, :renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

Please make sure you have **restarted the server** after installing the gem.

Comment: Restarting the server did it for me. Thanks.

Comment: This did not work for me. It works locally but on the server I am getting the same error.

Comment: did you restart the server ? try restarting the httpd service if you are running appache

Comment: I was using 'bootstrap-will_paginate' rather than 'will_paginate-bootstrap'. Fixing that and restarting the server did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you use gem [will_paginate-bootstrap](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/will_paginate-bootstrap) with rails 4.0 or later, you must have it available on all stages. See [Rails Upgrade Guide 3.2 to 4.0](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0). Before Rails 4.0 this was fine, to have it only in assets.

**This is right for rails 3.X or earlier:**

```
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', group: :assets
```

**It must be outside of any groups (on rails 4.0 and later):**

```
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Gemfile, I had will_paginate-bootstrap in my "assets" group... but it isn't just a set of assets. That class needs to be around in production. Moving it out of the assets group resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just using `will_paginate` and creating your own render works fine.

For bootstrap 4,throw [this code](https://gist.github.com/daino3/661d9742e2b9803e329a880f8c3ee529) into `config/initializers/will_paginate.rb`

Then, the code below into `application_helper.rb`:

```
  def will_paginate(collection_or_options = nil, options = {})
    if collection_or_options.is_a? Hash
      options, collection_or_options = collection_or_options, nil
    end
    unless options[:renderer]
      options = options.merge renderer: WillPaginate::ActionView::BootstrapLinkRenderer
    end
    super *[collection_or_options, options].compact
  end
```

And finally, call in the view like so:

```
nav aria-label="blah"
  = will_paginate @items
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to update 'bootstrap-will_paginate' in Gemfile to '0.0.10'

`gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'`

and use <%= will_paginate @mylist%>

it helped to me