# Uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::WriteXLSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-4

I'am trying to export data to Excel spread sheet in rails using "write_xlsx_rails" gem.

**Controller:**

```
def download
   render xlsx: "download", disposition: "attachment", filename:   "my_new_filename.xlsx"
end
```

**View(download.xlsx.wxlsx):**

```
    # Add a worksheet
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet

    # Add and define a format
    format = workbook.add_format # Add a format
    format.set_bold
    format.set_color('red')
    format.set_align('center')

     # Write a formatted and unformatted string, row and column notation.
     col = row = 0
     worksheet.write(row, col, "Hi Excel!", format)
     worksheet.write(1,   col, "Hi Excel!")

     # Write a number and a formula using A1 notation
     worksheet.write('A3', 1.2345)
     worksheet.write('A4', '=SIN(PI()/4)')
```

but I'm getting error like this:

> uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::WriteXLSX

Comment: Did you re-start the server after installing the gem? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588749/uninitialized-constant-actionviewcompiledtemplatescategory and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037955/uninitialized-constant-actionviewcompiledtemplatesbootstrappagination
These may help you solve your problem.

Comment: According to write_xlsx_rails documentation use `format.xlsx{render xlsx: "download", disposition: "attachment", filename:   "my_new_filename.xlsx"}`

Answer (score 0):

According to  write_xlsx_rails documentation, if you specify the file name you must use format for e.g.

```
def download
  respond_to do |format|      
   format.xlsx{render xlsx: "download", disposition: "attachment", filename: "my_new_filename.xlsx"}
  end
end
```